# How to write input text change event in angular custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to set decimals after changing of text box i.e 10 to after change 10.00
so I want to create a directive for this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Amount"/>

app.directive("editor", function(){
 return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.onblur('blur', function (e) {
             alert('as')
             // i want text box value here 
             return (value).toFixed(2);
        });
   }


        }
    };
});
```

[actually, I want a money input field 
that do not allow letters, initially set decimal value 0.00
and the first digit do not allow zero, I created different directives for this is it possible create one directive for this]

Answer (score 0):

Use `angular-input-masks`, Opinionated input masks for AngularJS

```
bower install --save angular-input-masks
```

This will help you to accomplish the task.

Define the number of decimals (default is 2):

```
<input type="text" name="field" ng-model="money" ui-money-mask>
```

For more details [Documentation](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks)